# Creating two dynamoDB tables in serverless.yml

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I'm try to add 2 tables to serverless.yml to link with DynamoDB.

A part of my code in serverless.yml:

```
...       
 resources:
      Resources:
        ItemsTable:
          Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
          Properties:
            TableName: "InvoiceConfig"
            AttributeDefinitions:
            - AttributeName: "providerName"
              AttributeType: "S"
            KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: "providerName"
              KeyType: "HASH"
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 2
              WriteCapacityUnits: 2
            TableName: "DifferentTermsPages"
            AttributeDefinitions:
            - AttributeName: "id"
              AttributeType: "S"
            - AttributeName: "providerName"
              AttributeType: "S"
            - AttributeName: "productType"
              AttributeType: "S"
            - AttributeName: "language"
              AttributeType: "S"
            - AttributeName: "terms"
              AttributeType: "L"
            KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: "id"
              KeyType: "HASH"
            - AttributeName: "providerName"
              KeyType: "HASH"
            - AttributeName: "productType"
              KeyType: "HASH"
            - AttributeName: "language"
              KeyType: "HASH"
            - AttributeName: "terms"
              KeyType: "HASH"
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 10
              WriteCapacityUnits: 10
```

Is that correct??

My tables are:

```
InvoiceConfig: with columns: providerName (String)
DifferentTermsPages: id (String), providerName (String), productType (String), language (String), terms (list)
```

Do I need more changes in serverles.yml? what is the meaning of the expressions "ReadCapacityUnits" and "WriteCapacityUnits"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be some separation between two resources (i.e. two DynamoDB tables).

**Note:-**

You can define only key attributes while creating the DynamoDB table. In other words, you don't need to define all other non-key attributes.

**Try this:-**

```
Resources:
ItemsTable:
  Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
  Properties:
    TableName: "InvoiceConfig"
    AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: "providerName"
      AttributeType: "S"
    KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: "providerName"
      KeyType: "HASH"
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 2
      WriteCapacityUnits: 2            
DifferentTermsPages:
  Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
  Properties:             
    TableName: "DifferentTermsPages"
    AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: "id"
      AttributeType: "S"
    KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: "id"
      KeyType: "HASH"
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 10
      WriteCapacityUnits: 10
```

**Read and Write capacity units:-**

> You specify throughput capacity in terms of read capacity units and
>   write capacity units:
>
> One read capacity unit represents one strongly consistent read per
>   second, or two eventually consistent reads per second, for an item up
>   to 4 KB in size. If you need to read an item that is larger than 4 KB,
>   DynamoDB will need to consume additional read capacity units. The
>   total number of read capacity units required depends on the item size,
>   and whether you want an eventually consistent or strongly consistent
>   read. One write capacity unit represents one write per second for an
>   item up to 1 KB in size. If you need to write an item that is larger
>   than 1 KB, DynamoDB will need to consume additional write capacity
>   units. The total number of write capacity units required depends on
>   the item size.

[Read and write capacity units](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html)

Answer (score 3):

## Short Answer:

**Read and Write Capacity Units are** the max size of data the db is allowed to processes per second, if you go over this amount in any second your request would throttle.

## Alternative:

It might be easier to just use [DynamoDB On-Demand](https://serverless.com/blog/dynamodb-on-demand-serverless/) and pay for the Db table usages rather than calculating WCU and RCU.

## Example

Here is an example of 3 tables added in a formatted manner and without semiquotes:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    myDynamoDBTable1:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: Table1
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: ColumnName1
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: ColumnName2
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: ColumnName1
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: ColumnName2
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1 
    myDynamoDBTable2:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: Table2
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: ColumnName1
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: ColumnName1
            KeyType: HASH
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    myDynamoDBTableN:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: TableN
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: ColumnName1
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: ColumnName1
            KeyType: HASH
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

## Additional Explanation with Examples:

Back to [Read/Write Capacity Mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html):

#### Write Capacity Units (WCU) formula: Round up (DataSize / 1KB)

**Example1:**
imagine you foresee a traffic of writing 10KB of data per second into the db. Using the WCU formula, you would need (10KB / 1KB) = 10WCU.

**Example2:**
Expecting writing traffic of 7.5KB of data to the db, we would need: (7.5KB / 1KB) = 8WCU

#### Reading Capacity Units (RCU) depends on Strongly or Eventually Consistent models.

**Strongly Consistent mode:** Round up (DataSize / 4KB)
**Eventually Consistent mode:** Round up(DataSize / 4KB) / 2